# How to create Progress Dialog in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am developing the application to receive some data from the internet while receiving the data I want to show the "Progress Dialog". I used **"AsyncTask"** in my application.

The question is **how to use it and how to show the percentage like 100%?**

Please suggest me and give me some example. 
Thank you and Sorry for my English.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. check the docs has an example

Comment: Since ProgressDialog is deprecated what might be the alternative.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To show the prgress dialog you can use the below code

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Your message..");
                dialog.show();
```

before you call the async task i.e. before `new YourTask.execute().`

and in the onPostExecute function of the asynctask You can use

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: For showing the progress percentage.You can check this example...[link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fallowing method:

```
public void launchBarDialog(View view) {
    barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image ...");
    barProgressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
    barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    barProgressDialog.setMax(20);//In this part you can set the  MAX value of data
    barProgressDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);//At this, you can put how many data is downloading by a time
                                                                     //And with the porcentage it is in progress
                        }

                    });

                    if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {

                        barProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Hopefully it works for you all.